# change supported / unsupported device list after publishing in play store

Tags: android, publishing

is it possible to change the list with unsupported devices even after the app is published? Can I exclude a specific device first and later include it again or will it stay excluded once it got removed from the supported list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have full control of authorizing devices that may or may not install your application. This option can be altered any time for any device.

The only thing that you cannot change after publishing your application is its pricing. Once you set your app to be free, it will always remain free. You cannot override it by putting the price. Besides that, everything is editable.